# Use property of one part of graph traverse as filter for other

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I want next:

1. Traverse part of graph
2. Take property from first traverse
3. Put it into other traversal as filter
4. Get filtered value

When I run next in Gremlin console:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV('a').property(id, 1).property('b',2)
g.addV('a').property(id, 2).property('b',2).property('c',3)
g.V(2).properties().key().limit(1).as('q').select('q')
g.V(2).properties().key().limit(1).as('q').V(1).properties().key()
g.V(2).properties().key().limit(1).as('q').V(1).properties().key().select('q')
g.V(2).properties().key().limit(1).as('q').V(1).properties().key().where(__.is('b'))
g.V(2).properties().key().limit(1).as('q').V(1).properties().key().where(__.is(select('q')))
```

I get:

```
gremlin>     g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin>     g.addV('a').property(id, 1).property('b',2)
==>v[1]
gremlin>     g.addV('a').property(id, 2).property('b',2).property('c',3)
==>v[2]
gremlin>     g.V(2).properties().key().limit(1).as('q').select('q')
==>b
gremlin>     g.V(2).properties().key().limit(1).as('q').V(1).properties().key()
==>b
gremlin>     g.V(2).properties().key().limit(1).as('q').V(1).properties().key().select('q')
==>b
gremlin>     g.V(2).properties().key().limit(1).as('q').V(1).properties().key().where(__.is('b'))
==>b
gremlin>     g.V(2).properties().key().limit(1).as('q').V(1).properties().key().where(__.is(select('q')))
gremlin>
```

So I can see that:

1. My first traverse path gets property of 'b'
2. Selecting by direct usage of literal 'b' works
3. Using projection to filter by 'b' does not works.

**So question is - how to use value from one part of traversal as filter of other traversal in case described above?**

My use case is that I have `prototype` vertex. I want to grapb all its properties(and may be values), and find all vertices which are similar to that `prototype`.

Other alternative is to store query inside property of `prototype`, read it and evaluate it to get vertices which are filtered by it.

I know that I can do application side join of strings, but I want to stay only in code less part of Gremlin to have proper provider portability.

**UPDATE:**

Example from official documentation:

```
gremlin> firstYear = g.V().hasLabel('person').
                           local(properties('location').values('startTime').min()).
                           max().next()
==>2004
gremlin> l = g.V().hasLabel('person').as('person').
                   properties('location').or(has('endTime',gt(firstYear)),hasNot('endTime')).as('location').
                   valueMap().as('times').
                   select('person','location','times').by('name').by(value).by().toList()
```

How can I use `firstYear` without having variables in console, but to reference that from query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your question was answered on the Gremlin Users list. [1] Copying the answer here for others that may search for the same question.

What you're looking for is:

```
g.V(2).properties().key().limit(1).as('q').V(1).properties().key().where(eq('q'))
```

See documentation for the [Where](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Ftinkerpop.apache.org%2Fdocs%2Fcurrent%2Freference%2F%23where-step&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGcoyVuW4pk8mhWQMvmkxtSa2aqfQ) Step to learn about the different usage patterns of where.

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/f1NfwUw9ZVI